# How to return a 2D array of enum in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, enums

I have a class called Maze. I have initialized a 2D array of enum (state) as a private class variable. How do I return the 2D array?

```
    namespace Assignment3
    { 
       enum state 
       { Blank, Hurdle, Start, End}
       public class Maze
       { 
         private state[,] states; 
         public Maze ()
         { 
           states=new state[20,20]; 
         }
         public enum[,] GetMazeState()
         {
           return states; 
         }
   }
```

Doing this gives an error of "method does not have a return type". I tried changing return type to state[,] but that gives error of "return type less accessible than the method which is understandable but then what should be the correct return type? I cannot make the states variable public as I'm implementing observer pattern to notify the observer classes of change in state.

Comment: Your enum is called `state` not `enum`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change return type to `state[,]` of `GetMazeState()` like

```
public state[,] GetMazeState()
{
    return states;
}
```

Comment: Did it. Gives this error:
inconsistent accessibility: return type 'state[*,*]' is less accessible than the method Maze.GetMazeState()

Comment: @hermain your enum has no access modifier (private, public, etc.) so it is `internal` by default. Your class and method are `public` meaning that another application could reference your library/application and use this class (it's public), but your enum is `internal` so that other application can't see it. You need to make your class internal or your enum public.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is the return type. `enum[,]` should be changed by `state[,]`.

Another is enum availability. `GetMazeState()` is public. So you need to add an access modifier with at least the same visibility to the enum.
So if You change `enum state` to `public enum state` it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the 2D array like this:

```
public state[,] GetMazeState()
{
    return states;
}
```